# Visual Studio Code cannot detect cygwin git.exe path

Tags: git, cygwin, visual-studio-code

I've just started using Visual Studio Code (on Windows) for new UI project I've just joined.  I have my Path environment variable configured to point to my cygwin git executable as follows:

C:\cygwin64\bin

I've verified that this is working by opening a Windows command prompt and successfully executing Linux commands.  However, when I open the git project in Visual Studio Code, which looks to the path to resolve its "git.path" configuration, I get the following error:

ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\cygdrive'

Explicitly configuration the Workspace Settings file (settings.json) doesn't work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: See the fix to part of this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69340165/61624 As for why you are getting that specific error, you'll need to show us what you set your git.path to.

Answer (score 6):

just create a symlink (windows): open a cmd prompt and use the following command:

```
mklink /j "C:\cygdrive" C:\actual\path\to\your\cygdrive
```

PS: For babun users, it would be your home directory:

```
mklink /j "c:\home" C:\Users\{user}\.babun\cygwin\home
```

Comment: This worked for me (babun), but path should user "Users", not "User".

Comment: After creating the link the error changes: `ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'D:\cygdrive\c'`
Note that my installation is in another drive.

Comment: My Babun's `fstab` has the cygdrive at `/` instead of `/cygdrive` and my error message was about not finding `C:\c`. Doing `mklink /j "C:\c" C:\ ` seems to have fixed it.

Comment: So I have a standard install of cygwin and I am confused as to what `C:\actual\path\to\your\cygdrive` should actually be. I have cygwin installed at C:/cygwin64

Comment: it depends on how you installed Cygwin, but the default Windows path to your Cygwin home directory is usually C:\cygwin\home\%USERNAME%

Comment: I ended up, creating a `C:/cygdrive/` folder, then in that folder, creating a symlink `C:/cygdrive/c/` that points to `C:/`. I hope it doesn't break anything else.

Comment: Can someone please explain what `C:\actual\path\to\your\cygdrive` should be? What is a "cygdrive" and how do I know where mine is? Assuming that I installed Cygwin to the default location.

Comment: Why is this getting votes? This doesn't solve the problem, it just kicks the can to the next issue. You can't use the cygwin git.exe in visual studio code by setting `git.path`: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/7998

Answer (score 0):

generate bare git.exe wrapper Cygwin's git works for me under Win 7, https://github.com/nukata/cyg-git

Answer (score -1):

I can not commet.
For babun users, the command should be

```
mklink /j "c:\cygdrive" C:\Users\{user}\.babun\cygwin\home
```

And after that, if you put your code in other path rather than under home, you should link the driver to home.For example, if your code path is D:\Codes\MyProject, you should run the command

```
mklink /j "C:\Users\{user}\.babun\cygwin\home\d" D:
```

Answer (score -5):

I had a similar problem.  Here is what fixed the issue for me.

- I had to include `git.exe` in the path. On my system it looks like this: `"git.path": "D:\\Programs\\Git\\bin\\git.exe"`.  VS Code seems to expect that the file is included in this path rather than just the folder location of the executable.
- I had to restart VS Code for the git path setting change to take effect.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Is your git installation the git from Cygwin or the git for Windows?

Comment: Git for Windows

Comment: @grahamaj Then your answer is irrelevant to the current conversation.