# Git in Visual studio code says file is modified even when there is no change

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, salesforce

I am using the Visual Studio Code for my salesforce development. I have some issues with Git as a repository. When I right-click on the package.xml and say Retrieve Source From Org, it is getting all the files from Org.

The problem is git extension is showing file is modified on the server even though I have a sample file in my local. I don't want to push all the files again and again to my git repo even when there is no change.

[image]

Any idea why this is happening and how to avoid it?

**Update:** I did git diff and it provides correct output. It only shows file changes that are modified. In this case only five.

Comment: what does command line `git status` tell you?

Comment: I got similar problem recently. It only happen when I delete the whole folder and replace with similar folder. Then, vscode git also show files with no changes. But when I stage all, files with no changes are no longer shown in staging area.

Comment: Is there a specific reason that you use Visual Studio Code? If you use it just because of solving conflicts or seeing git status, I can recommend another program.

Comment: `git status` displays the same list of files and says it is modified

Comment: Maybe VS Code reformat your files, can you share output of ```git diff```

Comment: `git diff` gives the correct output. It only displays files that are actually modified.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VS code source control populates with all the files (code and zip files) from my User folder on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54752138/vs-code-source-control-populates-with-all-the-files-code-and-zip-files-from-my)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I was able to resolve it by executing the following command

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

Documentation: [https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#:~:text=with%20these%20issues.-,core.autocrlf,-If%20you%E2%80%99re%20programming](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#:%7E:text=with%20these%20issues.-,core.autocrlf,-If%20you%E2%80%99re%20programming)

Comment: Funnily I had to set core.autocrlf to true to make my "modified" files disappear.. I'm using a git repo checked out on Windows that gets opened in a VS Code dev container running in Ubuntu.

Comment: This made it worse and made a file that didn't appear before as changed appear as changed even though it isn't 

Answer (score 52):

If we change the permission using then I also encountered that behavior. In order to overcome from this issue you can use the below commands.

```
git config core.filemode false
```

In case you want to apply for the global.

```
git config --global core.filemode false
```

*See also: [What are the consequences of git config core.filemode false?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69339954/3416774)*

Comment: That works for me, but what are the consequences? Does this mean my committed .sh files won't be pulled as executable by others?

Comment: This happens amongst others if you switch between Linux filesystem and Windows filesystem, for instance, if you switch from using VScode in CMD to VScode using WSL.

Comment: I had this while switching between WSL and Windows. Installing Remote WSL extension solved this issue.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/69341082/4996021 if you want to understand what this does. @DanielKaplan kindly asked his above question and got a thorough answer.

Comment: Faced sutiation when changed permitions to a folder on macOS. Solved my issue.

Answer (score 6):

If you run `git diff` and see an output such as:

```
diff --git a/folder/file.tex b/folder/file.tex
old mode 100725
new mode 100614
```

Run the following command to fix the issue.

```
git config --unset core.filemode
```

If this doesn't work after refreshing source control in VS Code, run the following command as well.

```
git config --global core.filemode false
```

Comment: `git config --unset core.filemode` worked like a charm and brought back the **actual** state of the repository

Answer (score 4):

I had to do both the `filemode` and the `autocrlf` options above, plus,

`git config core.whitespace cr-at-eol`

I'm on a windows system with a linux subsystem (wsl), looking at a primarily made-with-linux codebase.

I also had to do those options both for the git installed in the linux subsystem and then again for the windows version of git, since VSCode used one but my actual git commands I enter into linux bash.

Answer (score 2):

For me, these e command have fixed the issue:

```
git config --global core.filemode false
git config --global core.autocrlf false
git config --global core.whitespace cr-at-eol
```

[https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#:~:text=with%20these%20issues.-,core.autocrlf,-If%20you%E2%80%99re%20programming](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#:%7E:text=with%20these%20issues.-,core.autocrlf,-If%20you%E2%80%99re%20programming)

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-corefileMode

Answer (score 1):

If you are using cygwin and experiencing this issue, I have learned of a solution that doesn't require changing your git settings. [First, be aware that this is a known issue but it is not planned on being fixed.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/7998) After a bunch of research, I found this gist: https://gist.github.com/nickbudi/4b489f50086db805ea0f3864aa93a9f8 It consists of two files.

**cygpath-git-editor.sh:**

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# wrapper to convert linux paths to windows
# so vscode will work as a git editor with cygwin
# editor="/home/this/file.sh" in .gitconfig

# extract last argument (the file path)
for last; do true; done

# get all the initial command arguments
all="${@:1:$(($#-1))}"

# launch editor with windows path
code $all $(cygpath -w $last)
```

**cygpath-git-vscode.bat:**

```
@echo off

REM wrapper to convert linux paths to windows
REM so vscode git integration will work with cygwin
REM "git.path"="C:\\this\\file.bat" in settings.json

setlocal
set PATH=C:\cygwin\bin;%PATH%

if "%1" equ "rev-parse" goto rev_parse
git %*
goto :eof
:rev_parse
for /f %%1 in ('git %*') do cygpath -w %%1
```

I will now explain the steps to use these scripts:

1. Copy and paste the scripts to your local file system.
2. In cygpath-git-vscode.bat, change `set PATH=C:\cygwin\bin;%PATH%` to the correct path on your system. For me, that meant setting it to `set PATH=C:\cygwin64\bin;%PATH%`
3. Run `chmod +x <filename>` on each file. If you forget this step, you'll get a vague error about the command not being found.
4. Edit your visual studio code settings.json and set `git.path` to the windows path to cygpath-git-vscode.bat. e.g.,

   ```
   "git.path": "C:\\cygwin64\\home\\user\\cygpath-git\\cygpath-git-vscode.bat"
   ```
5. Restart visual studio code.

After those steps, only the modified files showed as modified in VS Code.

Comment: I tried these scripts, they worked for basic git status display, but trying to stage/unstage a file resulted in errors. I.e. these commands failed:
`git add -A -- C:\project\hxcalc\package.json` and `git reset -q HEAD -- C:\project\hxcalc\package.json` both results in `fatal: C:\project\hxcalc\package.json: 'C:\project\hxcalc\package.json' is outside repository at '/mnt/c/project/hxcalc'`. I tried the same commands in Cygwin bash, and indeed, Cygwin git doesn't seem to be able to handle Windows paths.

Comment: What worked for me is this: https://github.com/nukata/cyg-git
It's a tiny C wrapper that you compile with gcc (for my use case, regular Cygwin gcc worked), and a Zsh wrapper script that works similar to cygpath-git-vscode.bat, but also takes care of converting paths passed to git. I had to make a small change to this script to make it handle `rev-parse` commands that produce multiple lines of output (made a PR to the original repo).

Comment: @GenePavlovsky  Interesting. I don't think I can help with that because I do not get this error. I stage and unstage files with this setup.

Comment: Can you try an add or reset comand (with a Windows path) such as I listed before, in Cygwin bash? Does it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using cygwin bash you should know that there is issue related to this one, instead you can use git bash for windows and set it as default shell in vscode.